created laravel nova tool that should add a link to the navigation and a site if that link is clicked; however i am missing a step to make this happen
i have create a laravel nova tool with the artisan command. furthermore i added the new tool to the NovaServiceProvider. a new link shows up in the navigation, but noting is happening if i click it (i think there should be some site that shows the text: "We're in a black hole". i checked the page source and there is no actual link there. it is just the text.
i tried to add a route, but as there is no page to begin with this does not really make sense.
online, i found a few tutorials, but they all seem to overlook a step that i am missing. does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?
